# How does NuxtJS css extraction work for generated static websites?

Tags: css, vue.js, leaflet, nuxt.js

I am trying to generate a static website out of [my (minimal) code](https://github.com/shopozor/services/tree/dev/frontend/consumer-ui) with Nuxt. In that code, I integrate in particular the `tailwindcss` toolkit as well as `vue2-leaflet`. Upon

```
nuxt generate
```

I get two css files, one for the `tailwindcss` css and the other for the `leaflet` css. While the former file is fine and contains everything I need, the latter is pretty sparse:

```
.leaflet-tile-pane{z-index:200}@-webkit-keyframes leaflet-gestures-fadein{to{opacity:1}}@keyframes leaflet-gestures-fadein{0%{opacity:0}to{opacity:1}}
```

Of course, that makes my map render in a pretty strange way, because most of the css is missing. Here's my current `nuxt.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'universal',

  head: {
    title: pkg.name,
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: pkg.description }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },

  css: [
  ],

  plugins: [
    { src: '~plugins/leaflet.js', mode: 'client' }
  ],

  buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss'
  ],

  modules: ['@nuxtjs/apollo', 'nuxt-purgecss', ['nuxt-i18n', i18n]],

  [...]

  build: {
    extractCSS: true,
  }
}
```

Getting rid of the `extractCSS` ends up incorporating all the relevant css into the `index.html`. It works, but then I get the following error:

```
ERROR  Webpack mode only works with build.extractCSS set to *true*. Either extract your CSS or use 'postcss' mode
```

I'm not sure I understand how that whole css extraction works. Could someone enlighten me? Why is it not working with `extractCSS: true`? How can I make it work? Why is it working in SPA mode but not in static mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [`nuxt-purgecss`](https://github.com/Developmint/nuxt-purgecss) which is using [purgecss](https://github.com/FullHuman/purgecss) to strip unused CSS.

`purgecss` do scan HTML (or vue) files for CSS classes in use and then strip unused classes from final CSS bundle.

You can take a look at default `purgecss` configuration used by `nuxt-purgecss` [here](https://github.com/Developmint/nuxt-purgecss#defaults). The `paths` lists the paths `purgecss` will scan for CSS usage.

Because you are not using most of the `leaflet` css directly (in your components), its is necessary to configure `purgecss` to don't remove leaflet's css.

You can do that by [whitelisting](https://www.purgecss.com/whitelisting) (btw not sure if "comment" method will work in Vue\Nuxt)

You can read more [here](https://github.com/FullHuman/purgecss/issues/170) and [here](https://github.com/nuxt-community/tailwindcss-module/issues/25)

**Not tested!!**

```js
// nuxt.config.js
{
  purgeCSS: {
    whitelistPatterns: [/leaflet/, /marker/]
  }
}
```

---

#### Regarding the error message

Error message is from `nuxt-purgecss` module - it is clearly documented [here](https://github.com/Developmint/nuxt-purgecss#mode)

I don't have deep knowledge of Nuxt build process. So I just assume from the [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build#extractcss) that `extractCSS: true` will use [extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/faceyspacey/extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin/) to extract all CSS to separate CSS file, while (default) `extractCSS: false` will use `PostCSS` to extract all CSS and put it directly into the `<style>` tag of rendered page.

All of that doesn't matter IMHO because the root problem is the use of `purgecss` and the solution is to configure it correctly to whitelist `leaflet` CSS classes....

Comment: Works now perfectly. Thanks for the useful insight.